# RoboVM Admob Mediation

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, robovm, mobile-ad-mediation

I hope this is the right place to ask this question:

I've been trying to get chartboost to work on iOS via RoboVM (libGDX)
I'm using the Mobidevelop fork of RoboVM so the only robopods available to me right now is the Admob robopod backported by florianf: https://github.com/florianf/robovm-robopods

So to get Chartboost on iOS, my only option is to use Admob Mediation, but I'm not sure how to get that to work on RoboVM :/ please help if you can ! Thanks :)

I just need to figure out how to link network adapters/chartboost SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get chartboost in your ios app you can directly add chartboost framework and get your ads as required,

i used [robovm-robopods](https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods), though it was having some issue with admob but my major concern was to show interstitial ads.

The process is:

1. Get framework from [from official site](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220095-Download-Integrate-the-Chartboost-SDK-for-iOS) and paste your framework folder into your libs directory of ios module.
2. After you are done with this, open robovm.xml and add these lines

   libs


       ....
        StoreKit
       Chartboost
       AdSupport
3. Initialise the chartboost SDK and show ads. for more details you can use the robopods that you are using it has a sample for ios.